# Apache fails to start as Windows service with mod_wsgi

Tags: windows, apache, mod-wsgi

I'm using Apache 2.4, Python 3.5 and appropriate mod_wsgi from Gohlike binaries page, everything is 64-bit. Apache works as intended when it's started manually, but when I'm trying to start it as service it fails and produces

> httpd.exe: Syntax error on line 180 of C:/Apache24/httpd.conf: Cannot load c:/Users/<Username>/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35/Lib/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi.cp35-win_amd64.pyd
>   into server: \xcd\xe5 \xed\xe0\xe9\xe4\xe5\xed
>   \xf3\xea\xe0\xe7\xe0\xed\xed\xfb\xe9 \xec\xee\xe4\xf3\xeb\xfc
>   *(Specified module could not be found)*.

to Windows event log.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is solved. The error occured because Python installation wasn't system-wide.

Comment: Thank you so much lol, been stuck with this bug for the last 3 days... Confusing error messages from Event View doesn't not help at all. (The Event View is telling me that Apache isn't able to find the mod_wsgi.cp35-win_amd64.pyd, but the real problem was like you said, the Apache services wasn't able to find a python.exe to use)

Answer (score 2):

Add python to path before install

```
set PATH=E:\python35;%PATH%
httpd.exe -k uninstall
httpd.exe -k install
```